# Нахождение использование стилей

Tags: css

Можно ли как то определить используются ли подключенные css стили где то, на данной странице .
Допустим подключено 5 css файлов , как допустим, узнать используется 1 из них на определенной странице ?

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools на вкладке Audits показывает.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+U когда находишься на странице, на которой хочешь узнать какие файлы стилей используются, там в теге head ищи link rel="stylesheet" href="..."
Как уже сказано в комменте к твоему вопросу, жмём F12, находим вкладку Audits, жмём Run, получаем список файлов которые используются на странице, и какие при этом стили(классы, id, все правила) не юзаются на конкретной странице.

Comment: Да , это понятно , но не факт что те стили что подключены там , используются на данной странице .

Answer (score 1):

В Chrome 59 появилась новая фича. Вкладка Coverage показывает процент неиспользованного JS и CSS кода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кликнув по файлу он откроется на вкладке Source и там уже буду подсвечены конкретные неиспользованные участки кода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]